# XEN 4.1 missing from the Grub Menu

Tags: grub2, xen

I installed Xen with following Commands.

```
apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386
apt-get install xen-utils-4.1
apt-get install xenwatch
apt-get install xen-tools
apt-get install xen-utils-common
apt-get install xenstore-utils
apt-get install virtinst
apt-get install virt-viewer
apt-get install virt-manager
```

as given in http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/11/02/install-xen-4-1-and-setup-your-cloud-os-on-ubuntu-11-10/

But I cant see any entry for Xen 4.1 in my GRUB Menu upon reboot. (As soon as I install above listed packages)

Any solution? Please Help

Comment: I am using UBUNTU 11.10

Comment: have you installed the `linux-image-server` kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to setup xen.

The commands

```
apt-get install linux-image-server
update-grub
```

made a new entry for xen available in the boot menu.
(Thanks to fossfreedom for the hint.)